# Why does this scanf cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, scanf

I am writing a program to calculate the Information Entropy, This is the function of Entropy(H)

> [image: H(X) = -sigma(i = 1 to n){p(x_i)*log2(p(x_i)}]
>
> base 2 log is used here

And then here is my program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

typedef struct vars {
    char *var;
    float prob;
} CHOISES;

float infocont(float x);
float entropy(CHOISES *, int);
void onsig(int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int siz = 0;
    float H = 0.0;

    printf("input the number of vars: ");
    scanf("%d", &siz);
    //printf("echo: %d\n", siz);

    CHOISES chs[siz];

    signal(SIGSEGV, onsig);

    for (i = 0; i < siz; i++) {
        printf("%d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%s %f", chs[i].var, &chs[i].prob); /* HERE IS THE ERROR */
        //printf("echo: %s %f\n", chs[i].var, chs[i].prob);
    }

    H = entropy(chs, siz);
    
    printf("Entropy is %f\n", H);
}

void onsig(int signo)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "signal caught: %d\nSEGMENTATION FAULT\n", signo);
}

float infocont(float x) 
{
    return (log(1/x) / log(2));
}

float entropy(CHOISES chs[], int len)
{
     short i;
     float entropy;

     for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         entropy += chs[i].prob * infocont(chs[i].prob);
     }

     return entropy;
}
```

My problem is that when I input the first input and hit enter It makes a segmentation fault.
I used a debugger and I found that assigning data for the structure causes the segmentation fault.
That is when this code line executed

```
scanf("%s %f", chs[i].var, &chs[i].prob);
```

a segmentation fault occured.

but I can't think of error in this code.

Why does this scanf() make a segmentation fault?

Comment: For future ref: Also post the input entered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`chs[i].var` is a dangling pointer. You must `malloc` memory for it first.

```
chs[i].var = malloc(Max_str_len + 1);  //<--- this
scanf("%s %f", chs[i].var, &chs[i].prob);
```

Comment: Actually, first you must google for solutions how to read a string safely - you don't know how long it is. 1 char doesn't seem very much :-(

Comment: @gnasher729: Didn't see it was an %s

Comment: `malloc` should allocate `Max_str_len +1` bytes and not just `Max_str_len`

Comment: Also it's important to check whether `!chs[i].var` is `true` or not. Otherwise following `scanf` may cause `SegFault` again.

Comment: Good catch on the dangling pointer - OP current problem.  Yet `scanf("%s ...` is not much better than `gets()`.  Could use something like `scanf("%99s, ...` or better yet replace all `scanf()` with `fgets()`, yet that gets into solving OP's next problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("%d: ", i + 1);
    scanf("%s %f", chs[i].var, &chs[i].prob); /* HERE IS THE ERROR */
    //printf("echo: %s %f\n", chs[i].var, chs[i].prob);
}
```

Yes this code is indeed introducing bugs.

1. What if `siz < 10`? Then this will result in another `Segfault`.

   You should use `for (i = 0; i < siz; i++)` instead of `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)`
2. `chs[i].var` doesn't point to any valid memory location as it just contains the garbage and then `scanf()` attempts to store the string at that memory location which causes `SegFault`

   You should allocate memory first using `malloc`, `calloc` etc.
3. After allocating memory to `chs[i].var` don't forget to check for it's non-equivalence with `NULL` before `scanf()` as this may also cause `SegFault`.

So the working solution would be

```
for (i = 0; i < siz; i++)
{
    printf("%d: ", i + 1);
    chs[i].var = malloc((MAX_STRING_SIZE + 1)* sizeof(char));
    
    if(!chs[i].var)
    {
        printf("Memory could not be allocated!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    
    scanf("%s %f", chs[i].var, &chs[i].prob);
    printf("echo: %s %f\n", chs[i].var, chs[i].prob);
}
```

Comment: thank you, that "10" is a typo for this text. It was used in the debugging proccess.

Comment: @0xEDD1E Please check the updated answer. It covers another possible chance of `SegFault`